# Minimal installation to run a c++ "hello world" program using microsoft visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have download the visual studio community 2019, and I just want to run a normal c++ program such as the simplest "hello world" on it. However due to the limited hard drive space, I would like to install the minimal component. From [this post](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/hello-world-in-c-using-visual-studio-2019/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) by Microsoft, I see one picture of the following:

[image]

First I thought I don't need all the optional parts on my computer, when finished, there is an error reporting no header files such as `iostream`. So I go back and install the first component, still can't run. So I want to ask what else should I install. I don't want install more than I need.

Here is screenshot from mine (maybe contain some characters you don't recognize, but you can guess from the context), and it is basically what I have installed:

[image]

Comment: Just install the MSVC v142 stuff you already have checked and the various C++ options.  Ignore the test, build, share, options. You can also ignore C++ ATL and C++ MFC unless you plan on building apps with MFC and/or ATL, which are Windows class libraries to ease development around the C-level Windows APIs. I personally would include C++/CLI as it fills a useful niche role on Windows platforms as an intermediary between native C++ and managed .NET code.

Comment: @hacksalot Do I need windows SDK and CMake?

Comment: Windows SDK, yes -- not strictly necessary for "Hello World" stuff but I consider it part of a plain vanilla install. CMake can be installed separately, and is mostly used if you're building cross-platform for Windows / OS X / Linux etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiment, I found that at least these two optional components must be checked:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately to my knowledge, you need to install all the default downloads that Microsoft wants you to install initially. The other files besides the core C++ are tools for the compiler and your standard library which is important for a lot of C++'s functionality. if you dont want to have to re-invent the wheel for every task these standard libraries are immensely important. Things like Vector containers, Ofstream, and Maps are all based in these libraries. As well as that they are important for code compilation and just making visual studio run as a whole. That being said C++ projects and code dont, for small projects like you were saying, create that large of files so while the initial installation might take a lot of memory once your past that you should be fine.